# upload to google drive without authentication

Tags: python, google-drive-android-api

I have a working authentication&file-uploading to dropbox. Now, I would like to make this authentication&file-uploading to google drive. But I have a problem which is the following:

I need to login in google for the first time when I run the script above. In dropbox I don't need to login to upload a file.

Is it possible in google too?

Thanks

Google Drive:

```
   from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
   from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

   gauth = GoogleAuth()
   gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
   drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

   file5 = drive.CreateFile()
   # Read file and set it as a content of this instance.
   file5.SetContentFile('dark.jpg')
   file5.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

dropbox:

```
   import dropbox

   dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx')

   with open(file_name, "rb") as f: # path
       dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/' + pre_fn + current_time +'.jpg', mute = True)

   f.close()
```